If $f$ is a modular function of weight $2k$, then $v_p(f)=v_{g(p)}(f).$
I'm studying the Serre's book A Course in Arithmetic and at the beginning of the page 85 he says: "when $f$ is a modular function of weight $2k$, the identity $f(z)=(cz+d)^{-2k} f(g(z))$ shows that $v_p(f)=v_{g(p)}(f)$". I didn't understand this and would like some help.
I know that when we replace $z$ to $p$, the poles and zeros of $f(z)$ are related to the poles and zeros of $f(g(z))$ through the term $(cz+d)^{-2k}$. This term, apparently, does not provide zeros or poles, and then the equality would be proven. However, what if $p=-d/c$? This would cancel the denominator, which would imply the existence of a pole. This must be a problem, but I can't see it. In Serre's definition of a modular function, he asks that the function be meromorphic at infinity, but this means that the function can admit isolated poles. So, can we have $p=-d/c$? What would happen? In short, I need to prove the equality $v_p(f)=v_{g(p)}(f)$.
Recall that $v_p(f)$ is the integer such that $f/(z-p)^{v_p(f)}$ is holomorphic and non-zero at $p$.

Assuming $f$ is a modular function for something like $\Gamma = SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, the point $p = -d/c$ does not lie in the upper half-plane for any $g = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \ c & d\end{pmatrix}\in \Gamma$.

Why? Could you explain it, please? If $d<0$ and $c>0$, I thought $p$ is in there.

The upper half-plane consists of points $\sigma + it$ with $t > 0$.

That's right. Thank you!

Both $c$ and $d$ are real numbers, but the domain of modular functions in A Course in Arithmetic is $\mathcal{H} := \{ x + iy : x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \mathbb{R}^+ \}$, the upper-half plane.
This is why your fear that $p = -d/c$ cannot happen: this $p$ is not in $\mathcal{H}$.
There is some subtlety concerning showing that $\nu_\infty(f) = \nu_{g(\infty)}(f)$ that Serre largely ignores.
On the one hand, this is because Serre looks only at modular forms with respect to $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$, for which there is only one equivalence class of cusp, and the "only cusp" is $\infty$. If you agree to work in (or "near") the standard fundamental domain, then it doesn't matter. This is what Serre does to prove the next theorem that follows in the text.
On the other hand, this is because it is more complicated to actually define what it means to be holomorphic or meromorphic at a general point $c$ on the boundary of $\mathcal{H}$. This requires understanding the complex manifold structure of the compactification of $\Gamma \backslash \mathcal{H}$. See Diamond and Shurman, or Miyake, or Bump, or any book on modular forms to see this carried out in practice. It's not hard, but it is a bit complicated and the added difficulty doesn't give much if you only look at modular forms on $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$.
